# LinkExtractor for xpath-ed response TypeError: unhashable type: 'SelectorList'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `scrapy 2.5` and `python 3.8`

Currently my source code is like this below.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class YahooSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yahoo'
    allowed_domains = ['news.yahoo.com']
  
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://news.yahoo.com/search?p=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A0&ei=utf-8']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        xlink = LinkExtractor()
        for link in xlink.extract_links(response): 
            print("GETLINK:{0}".format(link)) #OK I can get the link of page.

        contents = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'contentsWrap')]") # xpath-ed div class contents
        
        for link in xlink.extract_links(contents):
            print("GETLINK:{0}".format(link)) # error TypeError: unhashable type: 'SelectorList'
        pass
```

It shows `TypeError: unhashable type: 'SelectorList'`

I understand the meaning of this error,

but Is there any way to use extract_links after xpath-ed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to extract links from a selector.

Use restrict_xpaths and extract links from the response.

(Also notice that you're using the wrong xpath, there's no 'contentsWrap' class...)

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class YahooSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yahoo'
    allowed_domains = ['news.yahoo.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://news.yahoo.com/search?p=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A0&ei=utf-8']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        xlink = LinkExtractor()
        for link in xlink.extract_links(response):
            print("GETLINK:{0}".format(link))

        # maybe: ???
        #xlink.restrict_xpaths = ['//div[contains(@class, "contents")]']

        xlink.restrict_xpaths = ["//div[contains(@class,'contentsWrap')]"]  # xpath-ed div class contents

        for link in xlink.extract_links(response): # this is empty
            print("GETLINK:{0}".format(link))
        pass
```

Comment: Today every answer of mine got downvoted (even though every one of them worked, and two of them got accepted). If you don't agree with my solution please let me know so I can improve. BTW, this solution also works: from scrapy doc ' extract_links(response)
    Returns a list of Link objects from the specified response.'

Comment: Thank you for your comment @SuperUser Your suggestion works well and , very good explanation. I can solve the problem.